# Hibernate Null Pointer on save object

Tags: mysql, macos, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

So I'm running a springboot application and when I run on OSX I get a null pointer. When I run the same application on a ubuntu vm it works just fine, as well as someone else OSX computer. I can't figure out what would cause this. I have tried forcing maven to re-download the hibernate library but it made no change. The model extends JPARepository, and has appropriate mappings. I'm able to create the tables, as well as read from the db, just not write to it. Not sure what code might be relevant.

```
Hibernate: insert into Organization (version, date_created, last_updated, name, org_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.handleAndClearWarnings(SqlExceptionHelper.java:320)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logAndClearWarnings(SqlExceptionHelper.java:273)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:529)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.release(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:421)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.releaseStatement(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:82)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:61)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.persist(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.persist(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:433)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:421)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:506)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.save(Unknown Source)
at com.<COMPANY>.<PACKAGE>.DevelopmentDataBootstrap.doBootstrap(DevelopmentDataBootstrap.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:759)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
at com.<COMPANY>.<PACKAGE>.SDKPortalApplication.main(SDKPortalApplication.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Which Spring Boot - Hibernate versions are you dealing with?

Comment: I'm using 1.2.7.RELEASE, the latest one gives me dependency errors for JSON packages.

Comment: Any other error ,warnings before that trace ?

Comment: No, no other errors.

Comment: nor warnings ? (i.e. you only have INFO log level in log file ?)

Comment: I have debug down to info and everything else works just fine. (I only posted the line before the error onwards to be brief)

Comment: I lied the only warning is Could not find matching type descriptor for requested Java class [java.util.Set]; using fallback (the log and warn color are to close together)

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert` SQL statement seems to be throwing a warning or not properly performing in the OSX system. Your stack trace points to [this line](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/spi/SqlExceptionHelper.java#L320) of code in the Hibernate version (4.3.11.Final) used in your Spring Boot. That's the whole failing method:

```java
@SuppressWarnings({"ThrowableResultOfMethodCallIgnored"})
public void handleAndClearWarnings(
        Statement statement,
        WarningHandler handler) {
    // See HHH-9174.  Statement#getWarnings can be an expensive call for many JDBC libs.  Don't do it unless
    // the log level would actually allow a warning to be logged.
    if (LOG.isEnabled(Level.WARN)) {
        try {
            walkWarnings( statement.getWarnings(), handler );
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            // workaround for WebLogic
            LOG.debug( "could not log warnings", sqlException );
        }
    }
    try {
        // Sybase fail if we don't do that, sigh...
        statement.clearWarnings();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle) {
        LOG.debug( "could not clear warnings", sqle );
    }
}
```

You are getting the NullPointerException in `statement.getWarnings()`, which suggests `statement` reaches with `null` value. You should verify your database versions in both systems and check your schemes match in.

Anyway, Hibernate should handle a possible null value here, from my point of view.

Comment: How would you go about verifying the db versions? I've installed mysql through homebrew.

Comment: Check for the mysql version used in your OSX computer and make sure it's the same as the working system have. Then check that the database scheme is exactly the same for every system. As a last resort, try to figure out which query does Hibernate try to execute and reply it to your DB directly, to see what kind of warning is throwing.

Comment: As for the second part any insert statements fail. It's able to create tables and read from the db, just not save. That's what makes this really strange to me.

Comment: This method is supposed to be called when database warning happen (not failures)

Comment: I'm also able to make the insert statement that appeared just before the crash (with random information put in)

Comment: It seems that the failing code is about a Log warning and not a DB warning.